# sql command show highest count for year 2000

Tags: sqlite

I have a  table (actor) in the database(movie)

| nationality | gender | year | actor | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | male | 2005 | Smith | 6 |
| USA | male | 2005 | Jones | 8 |
| USA | male | 2005 | Edwards | 8 |
| USA | male | 2005 | Rubio | 10 |
| Canada | male | 2005 | Thompson | 6 |
| Canada | male | 2005 | Watson | 8 |
| Australia | male | 2005 | Hopkins | 8 |
| Australia | male | 2005 | Howard | 10 |
| UK | male | 2005 | Harper | 8 |
| UK | male | 2005 | Palmer | 7 |
| UK | male | 2005 | Robinson | 10 |
| USA | female | 2005 | Love | 9 |
| USA | female | 2005 | Jonas | 6 |
| USA | female | 2005 | Nilson | 8 |
| USA | female | 2005 | Cruz | 11 |
| Canada | female | 2005 | Davidson | 7 |
| Canada | female | 2005 | Del Ante | 9 |
| Australia | female | 2005 | Hope | 11 |
| Australia | female | 2005 | Capa | 12 |
| UK | female | 2005 | Bernard | 22 |
| UK | female | 2005 | Freeman | 23 |
| UK | female | 2005 | Simson | 10 |
| USA | male | 2015 | Mitchell | 6 |
| USA | male | 2015 | Jona | 8 |
| USA | male | 2015 | Edwards | 8 |
| USA | male | 2015 | Rubio | 11 |
| Canada | male | 2015 | Troyson | 6 |
| Canada | male | 2015 | Watson | 8 |
| Australia | male | 2015 | Hopkins | 8 |
| Australia | male | 2015 | Howard | 10 |
| UK | male | 2015 | Harper | 8 |
| UK | male | 2015 | Palmer | 7 |
| UK | male | 2015 | Robinson | 10 |
| USA | female | 2015 | Love | 9 |
| USA | female | 2015 | Jonas | 6 |
| USA | female | 2015 | Nilson | 8 |
| USA | female | 2015 | Cruz | 11 |
| Canada | female | 2015 | Davidson | 7 |
| Canada | female | 2015 | Del Ante | 9 |
| Australia | female | 2015 | Hope | 11 |
| Australia | female | 2015 | Capa | 12 |
| UK | female | 2015 | Shaw | 12 |
| UK | female | 2015 | Freeman | 23 |
| UK | female | 2015 | Samuels | 12 |

Now I would like to know which actor and actress of every country played most in the year 2005 in the order of counts in ascending order.

I am expecting these output:

| nationality | gender | year | actor | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | female | 2005 | Freeman | 23 |
| Australia | female | 2005 | Capa | 12 |
| USA | female | 2005 | Cruz | 11 |
| USA | male | 2005 | Rubio | 10 |
| Australia | male | 2005 | Howard | 10 |
| UK | male | 2005 | Robinson | 10 |
| Canada | female | 2005 | Del Ante | 9 |
| Canada | male | 2005 | Watson | 8 |

I try these code, but got not the desired solution

```
SELECT nationality, gender, year,actor, max(count) as count from (actor) where year='2005'
```

Comment: What does *highest temperature for year 2000* have to do with your table?

Comment: sorry, was a mistake

Comment: Then you need to fix your title

Comment: I have done it, is there a better title?

Comment: Still have 2000, which should not be there. 2005 shouldn't be there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```sql
SELECT nationality, gender, year, actor, max(count) AS count
FROM actor
WHERE year = 2005
GROUP BY nationality, gender
ORDER BY count DESC
```